# Binary operation defined as $a*b=a+b-ab$

Tags: binary-operations

Binary operation '*' defined as $a*b=a+b-ab$ on a set $A=R\setminus\left\{0,1\right\}$ where $R$ is Set of Reals

Is this binary operation closed under the above operation on above set $A$

I thought it is not closed since if $a=b=2$ then $$2*2=0$$ which is not in set $A$.

But my book answer is It is closed. What is my error?

Comment: You have made no error. The book is wrong.

Comment: If the set is as you have defined it and the binary operation is as you've defined it then the set is not closed under that operation.

Comment: It should say $A=\Bbb R-\{1\}$. Then $A$ is a group isomorphic to $\Bbb R^\times$. Good catch.

Comment: My book says since $0,1$ are not in the Set, the pair $(2,2)$ will not be in the domain of Binary operation as Binary operation is a function from $A\times A$ to $A$. So the binary operation is closed.

Comment: any comment please?